# EmberJS Mirage Dependent attributes do not update on patch

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I have declared a properties in a Mirage factory as below and using Dependent attributes as found in the [docs](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/data-layer/factories#dependent-attributes).

```
price() {
  return faker.finance.amount(100000, null, 0);
},

priceDisplay() {
  return '$' + this.price;
}
```

When I do a patch to update `price` I expect `priceDisplay` to update as well like a `computed` property however this is not the case.

Does anyone know if this is possible or is this a Mirage limitation?

Comment: It seems this is not possible from within the factory but you can manually do it from the Mirage config.

Comment: I think it will be good to move the logic of price transform out of the Mirage into model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirage factory are meant to generate testing data:

> Factories are classes that help you organize your data-creation logic, making it easier to define different server states during development or within tests.

The factory is only run once by `server.create('foo')` or `server.createList('foo', 10)` to create initial data for the records. This helps you to avoid code duplication in tests and scenarios. But it's not a model representing that record.

Actually Mirage does not support something like computed properties out of the box. But you could achieve it by [customizing the serializer](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/data-layer/serializers#customizing-serializers) used. Overriding the [`serialize` method](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/api/modules/ember-cli-mirage/serializer~Serializer#serialize) should do the trick:

```js
// serializers/product.js

import { JSONAPISerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';

export default JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  // This is how to call super, as Mirage borrows [Backbone's implementation of extend](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend)
  let json = Serializer.prototype.serialize.apply(this, arguments);

  json.priceDisplay = '$' + json.price;

  return json;
});
```

But from your example given I would question if returning a formatted string from the API is the right approach. Formatting data should be a concern of the client in my opinion. Otherwise you will quickly run into limitations if you need to support localization or require different formats in your client.